# UI Grid scroll to focus is not working on newly added row when placed at bottom of the grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Scroll to focus is not working on a newly added row when the new item is added to the bottom of the table.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5325 discusses this issue.

The plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/OSbiB5C0RDPsqXJV0yjy?p=preview given there as solution is working as expected when the new item is added at the top.

i.e.    `$scope.gridOptions.data.unshift(newobj);`

But if I do this `$scope.gridOptions.data.push(newobj);` It is not working.

I'm using this logic to shift the focus to the newly added row

```
            var rowIndex = $scope.gridOptions.data.length-1;
            var colIndex = 1;
            $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus($scope.gridOptions.data[rowIndex], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]);
```

The newly added row is not visible. But if I scroll down to the bottom I'm able to see the new row.

Comment: This is definitely an issue with `ui-grid`, here is a [plnkr with workaround](http://plnkr.co/edit/aRxPxeJAQTJaeS2xcsq8?p=preview), but this doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, do you have any update ? With this workaround, new line is not entirely visible